# Is motion a form of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, dissipation

I think I am running into a semantics difficulty.

Loosely speaking when energy is converted from potential to kinetic is the motion a form of energy?   Let us use an example:

> A ball drops to the ground.  The gravitational potential energy  is converted to things like heat and sound.  The friction of the ball heats up the air which means it  imparts motion to the air molecules since that is what heat is and similarly when it strikes the ground molecules on the surface of the ground are put to motion and the motion spreads across the surface until it is all "consumed". It also imparts motion to itself from within it's own molecules. You would hear a "swoosh" as it travels through the air from the friction and a "bang" when it hits the ground.

Should we assume the potential energy has been converted all to imparting motion to the molecules?

So what happens to the motion?  Does it keep propagating from one form to another for ever? since energy cannot be destroyed ...that motion must never stop completely.  It's just that we can no longer detect it..maybe?

Comment: Motion by itself is not a form of energy. The difference in velocities to an influenced object is the energy one can measure and use.

Comment: I'm  ok with that.  You can call it " the difference in velocities" but then I am still left with the same question.  Where did the "motion" or in your case where did the "difference in velocities" go?

Comment: It goes to the kinetic energy of other particles, or to potential energy of interacting particles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are somehow trying to invoke a sort of "law of conservation of motion" based on the fact that

1. you noticed that energy, in the form of heat, has a kinetic interpretation at a microscopic level,
2. a "law of conservation of energy" exists, under certain assumptions.

While both 1 and 2 are valid points, there is no sensible way to regard "motion" as a conserved quantity.
Consider, for example, the act of loading a spring. Where has "motion" gone, before you decide to release it?

Comment: Thank you for understanding what I was asking.  I noticed one and two and then I was trying to do just what you said.  I guess when I think about it it seems a little silly on my part.  Motion is an artifact of transferring the energy so your spring example clears up my confusion.